# How can i make a gauge like this?

Tags: iphone, uiprogressview

I hope make a gauge like in this as image.

[image]

I don`t find sample souce or article.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that subclassing UIProgressView ( On iOS ) or NSProgressIndicator ( On Mac ).

Simply override - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  and do your custom drawing there.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.backgroundColor set];
    UIRectFill(rect); // draw the background


    // determine the size of the "progress"
    float size = (rect.size.width/100)*self.progress;
    [[UIColor blueColor] set]; // blue progress
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y, size, rect.size.height));
}
```

I am not sure that this will do it, haven't tested it but it *should* for a very basic progressIndicator

Comment: UIActivityIndicator isn't really designed to be subclassed out of the box. It might work, of course; have you successfully done this yourself?

Comment: Then subclass UIView, haven't tried it myself, add a property of progress and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer should be useful:

[Custom UIActivityIndicator, that is part of customized Framework or as a Sub Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822080/custom-uiactivityindicator-that-is-part-of-customized-framework-or-as-a-sub-clas)

Basically, code your own. If you don't know how, start learning how, and ask plenty of (good) questions along the way!